Chartjs line chart with tension not filling whole area?
I am using Chartjs(4.4.3) and react-chartjs-2(5.2.0) to show line chart in ui
I am having issue with area fill in line chart,
It is not filling completely for certain width
It happens only on latest chrome browser in mac
it works when i remove tension
Can you please tell me what needs to be change in order to make it work,
Heres sandbox link- Line Chart

Code -
const chartData = {
    xAxisPlots: [
      ["JAN", "2024"],
      ["FEB", "2024"],
      ["MAR", "2024"],
    ],
    pointTootTip: ["$293652.15", "$703695.82", "$14872.33"],
    pointData: [293652.15, 703695.82, 14872.33],
  };

  const data = {
    labels: chartData.xAxisPlots,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "",
        data: chartData.pointData,
        borderColor: "#0289AA",
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(2, 137, 170, 0.2)",
        fill: true,
      },
    ],
  };

  const options = {
    onClick: function (evt: ChartEvent, element: ActiveElement[]) {
      if (element[0]?.index >= 0) {
        pointCallback(element[0]?.index);
      }
    },
    animation: {
      duration: 0,
    },
    responsiveAnimationDuration: 0,
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        ticks: {
          callback: function (value: number | string) {
            return "C100";
          },
          font: {
            size: 13,
            weight: "bold" as "bold",
          },
          color: "#656579",
          maxTicksLimit: 6,
        },
      },
      x: {
        offset: chartData.xAxisPlots.length === 1 ? true : false,
        ticks: {
          maxRotation: 0,
          maxTicksLimit: 13,
          font: {
            size: 12,
            weight: "bold" as "bold",
          },
          color: "#656579",
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      filler: {
        propagate: true,
      },
      tooltip: {
        padding: 10,
        caretPadding: 15,
        caretSize: 0,
        cornerRadius: 20,
        xAlign: "center" as "center",
        yAlign: "bottom" as "bottom",
        displayColors: false,
        backgroundColor: "#0289AA",
        bodyColor: "#FFFFFF",
        bodyFont: {
          size: 12,
          weight: "bold" as "bold",
        },
        callbacks: {
          label: function ({ dataIndex }: { dataIndex: number }) {
            return chartData.pointTootTip[dataIndex];
          },
          title: function () {
            return "";
          },
          beforeLabel: function () {
            return "";
          },
        },
      },
    },
    tension: 0.5,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
  };

I added filler plugin (Chart.register(Filler)) still not working
Earlier I thought issue was with animation, so I turned it off, even after turning it off, it still doesn’t completely fill.

I can't reproduce your issue, your sandbox shows perfect fill with latest chrome (126.0.6478.115 / x86_64), macOS 14.5 screenshot. A possibly similar issue has been reported before but never solved as not reproducible. I tried several settings and widths and looked into the source code to see where this may come from but to no avail.

Is your issue always happening / at any window width /  with other than default filler plugin drawTime values? Is it happening with this fiddle too? If so, please share the code in the textarea (e.g., paste it into a jsfiddle javascript pane) so we can set up a reproducible case.

I was able to exactly replicate your size and position values from your data, but the fill is still perfect for me.

I also identified and extracted the canvas rendering context functions called by chart.js to fill this curve, with the exact call parameters for the particular case for which you sent your data. They are in this fiddle which doesn't use chart.js at all. Please let me know if you get the error there too, and the device pixel ratio displayed. The same for this fiddle that only contains one bezier curve in the region where you get the gap. These at least, will tell us if the issue is with chart.js or not.

I saw that this issue exist in both the fiddle you provided. I am using macbook pro 13inch screen on chrome browser. device pixel ratio = 2. Can you tell me who to report for this issue to be solved?

I find the fact that the issue is always reproducible on your system encouraging -- it doesn't seem to be some hardware malfunctioning occasionally. I'd want to find out if other people having the same hardware are experiencing the same problem, but I wouldn't know where to ask. As it appears in the latest fiddle, (unless it is a hardware issue) it's a problem with chrome not rendering a valid canvas fill as expected, so a good place to report it might be with chrome issues
